# Multiselect drop down list not working in ASP MVC3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, multi-select, html.listboxfor

I'm trying to learn how to use the `MultiSelectList` in my ASP MVC3 site but not getting the desired results. I can display the four values I'd like to show, however you can only click on one at a time. Again, this is my first attempt so please let me know if you see what I'm doing wrong.

**View Model**

```
//Create as array to hold multiple values
[DisplayName("Channel Code")]
public string[] searchChannelCode { get; set; }

//Drop down list objects
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChannelCodes { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
 ViewModel.ChannelCodes = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                            select z.ChannelCode)
                           .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                              { Text = x, Value = x })
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToList();
```

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.searchChannelCode)
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.searchChannelCode, 
                        new MultiSelectList(Model.ChannelCodes, "Text", "Value"))
```

Here is the result....: [image]

Comment: You can select multiple with SHIFT key

Comment: Yes, you can select multiple values on the web page, but they are still not being sent back to the controller. Just the highest selected value (ie only `H` is sent if both `H` and `K` are selected

Comment: How does your POST controller method look?

Comment: Nevermind, that's my mistake. It works as you mentioned. It is, however, not exactly what I'm looking for. Is it always necessary to hit "Shift" or "Control" to select two values if you're using the `MultiSelectList`?

Comment: I think yes. Maybe you can use some jQuery multiselect lib to solve that problem. Or even better use checkboxes.